# Google App Script: Speed up / alternative to loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, loops

I am a newbie on Google App Scripts. So far so good. Trying to do some of the stuff I used to do in an MsAccess DB. I think I have hit a bit of a problem, which could be related to the sheer amount of data I have. To illustrate my problem:

I have two arrays:

```
**Array1**

ID || Name <br>
0001 || Peter<br>
0005 || Arthur<br>
0008 || Gloria<br>
0010 || Martin<br>
0014 || Jess <br>


**Array2**

ID || Age <br>
0001 || 23<br>
0002 || 18<br>
0005 || 24<br>
0010 || 7<br>
```

As you can imagine, I want to produce something like:

```
**Array3**

ID || Name || Age <br>
0001 || Peter || 23<br>
0005 || Arthur|| 24 <br>
0010 || Martin || 7<br>
```

I have used the most simple code I can think of to the 'join':

```
for (var a=0; a<array1.length; a++) {
    for (var b=0; b<array2.length; b++) {
        if (array1[a][0] == array2[b][0]) {
            array3.push([array1[a][0],array1[a][1],array2[b][1]); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is: array1 is 70,000 entries long, and array2 is about 10,000 entries long, meaning the code runs out of time.

What would you guys do?

Comment: How do you get array "a" --- are you creating it?

Comment: Also, have you thought about using a free database, like mysql or postgre? :)

Comment: If your data is sorted numerically by "id" you should "find" the id by looking at the halfway-point, and then comparing it with the first point... if the id requested is greater than the half point, look at the next half point... ect.

Comment: @CodyG. Hi Cody. I am getting my arrays from google sheets. The getValues only takes a few seconds, so I don't think I have a problem there. Is the loop that is killing me!

Comment: @CodyG. Hi Cody. That is the other option I have been considering, but I have a lot of services integrated in Google (email, drive, forms), so it seems like giving google a shot will be a good option. If everything fails I will just go to an online DB...

Comment: @CodyG. Hi Cody. Yes, bot 'IDs' are numeric and sorted. I am not sure what your suggested solution would look like. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Create an auxiliary object whose property names are the id values from array2 (or array1; you could try both and see which is faster):

```
var a2map = {};
for (var a = 0; a < array2.length; a++)
  a2map[array2[a][0]] = array2[a];
```

Now you can iterate through array1 looking for matches:

```
for (var a = 0; a < array1.length; a++)
  if (array1[a][0] in a2map)
    array3.push([ array1[a][0], array1[a][1], a2map[array1[a][0]][1] ]);
```

Your original algorithm will have a runtime that's roughly proportional to `70000 * 20000`, which is a big number. This one will be closer to just `90000` or so, making it many thousands of times faster.